# assemble numpy array from different hdf5 datasets in one file

Tags: python, numpy, file-io, hdf5

So I have this large hdf5 file that features multiple large datsets. I am accessing it with h5py and want to read parts of every of those datasets into a common ndaray. Unfortunately, slicing across datasets is not supported, so I was wondering, what the most efficient way is, to assemble the ndarray with those datasets given the circumstances?

Currently, I am using something along the following lines:

```
 with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
            executor.map(assemble_array, range(NrDatasets))
```

where the function assemble_array reads in the data into a predefined ndarray buffer of appropriate size, but this is not fast enough :/

Can anyone help?

Comment: How are you creating the array? If you are using `.append()` you might be interested in this SO Q&A that addresses a similar issue: [saving and loading large numpy matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58685930/10462884)

Comment: thats pretty much what I am doing already. I pre-allocate a buffer of appropriate size and then loop over the hdf5 datasets and write each one in its associated position.